# Seaborn Heatmap getting truncated

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap with some data. The code I'm using follows:

```
seaborn.heatmap(shift_summary, annot=True, cmap='Reds', square=True)
plt.show()
```

However, the top and bottom edges of the chart get cut off and I have to scroll to see it all

[image: seaborn heatmap]

I have tried using `pyplot.subplots(figsize=(7,10))` before creating the plot, and the same chart was created but scaled to fit the new window size.

Any help is appreciated!